# How do you close Skype?

Tags: windows, skype

Whenever i try and close Skype on Windows, whether through the X on the top bar, or by right-clicking on the taskbar, it just minimizes it, instead of closing it.

How are you supposed to just quit??

Comment: Have you looked in the system tray and closed it via that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has an option "Quit Skype". From the Windows Taskbar > right click the "Skype" icon and select "Quit  Skype" option to close the application.

[image]

Comment: I thought i had tried that... I'll have to see next time i'm on Windows (generally a Linux user).

Answer (score 4):

Right click the Skype system tray icon and click "Quit Skype"

Comment: No, that just minimizes it, as i said in the question.

Comment: @Scimonster - This actually will close `Skype`.  It uses the same mechanic as right clicking on the `Skype` icon located on the `Windows Taskbar`

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the skype instance in the taskbar and then click `Quit Skype`

[image]